# Can I use Homebrew (macOS package manager) over Tor?

Tags: mac, packages

I found [Can I use APT over Tor?](https://support.torproject.org/apt/apt-over-tor/) (Debian and Ubuntu).

I wish to use [Homebrew](https://github.com/homebrew) over Tor and didn't find any info with a web search.

> The missing package manager for macOS (or Linux).

Why do i come to the question. I use a VPN which is friendly towards Torrent users. Many sites block my VPN endpoints and therefore I can't install all the software. Most of the time, however, the sites are still accessible via Tor, i.e. only blocked for my VPN provider.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! To make things as simple as possible - use a box like raspberry pi or similar to make it a tor-gateway: it can route **all** the traffic through the tor instance installed on it, so all your package managers e.t.c. will be just using Tor natively without ever knowing it! One remark here: if you'll have to reach the dot-onion addresses at the same time - do not forget to point your client's(macOS) DNS address to the raspberry pi routing box's IP where `DNSPort` from tor will be listening - it's a common issue that everything goes fine from DHCP but because of the client-side problem it's a DNS issue